# python non None default values

Tags: python, default-value

Programmer A writes the following function:

```
def compute_value(threshold = sys.float_info.max):
   ...
   return value
```

which has the optional parameter threshold which in a natural way has the maximum float value as a default to represent "no threshold".

Programmer B has also a representation for a threshold, but uses None to represent the absence of threshold. Unfortunately the compute_value function does not raise any exception if threshold=None but gives the incorrect answer. Hence a bug when programmer B passes None as threshold.

I would say that the best solution is to change the function in

```
def compute_value(threshold = None):
    if threshold is None:
        threshold = sys.float_info.max
    ...
    return value
```

since this function is more general than before, as it handles the None value in a way which makes sense.

This poses the question: is it always best to use only None as default values?

It is not the first time that functions having default parameters different from None cause trouble to me. In other situations I was finding myself to remove None values from a kwargs dictionary...

Another related (maybe silly) question. Actually programmer B modified the function above as follows:

```
def compute_value(threshold = sys.float_info.max):
    if threshold is None:
        threshold = sys.float_info.max
    ...
    return value
```

which is perfectly correct but seems bad to me. Bad because sys.float_info.max is repeated twice... but: is this a violation of the DRY principle? Because, strictly speaking, also None is repeated twice in the first implementation and both None and sys.float_info.max are constants.

Comment: Variable sys.float_info.max is accessible by importing it in your script from sys module, so I don't understand why to pass its value to the parameter

Comment: "Unfortunately the compute_value function does not raise any exception if threshold=None but gives the incorrect answer" -- I'm having a hard time coming up with a time when you _wouldn't_ get an exception if you have `None` and are using it as a `float`... The only case I can come up with is `if x:` where `x` could be a `float` or `None`, but that's a pretty small corner if that's the only way you're using a variable named `threshold` ...

Comment: @mgilson Just being nitpicky here, but `if x:` wouldn't be the smart thing to do when checking between None and a float, since x=0 will also trigger the condition.

Comment: To tell the whole story I'm actually using pandas.DataFrame.between(min_value,max_value) which (for some reasons I don't know) accepts None but threats it as a -INF value. And I'm not using sys.float_info.max but numpy.finfo(float).max

Comment: @Dhara -- That's exactly my point.  There is no good use that I can think of and only one bad use in which `None` could masquerade as a `float` without raising an exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This really boils down to whether or not you (the API provider) think that `None` should be a valid argument to pass to the function.  Personally, in this case, I think I would use `sys.float_info.max` and disallow the use of `None`.  After all, why should `None` go about masquerading as a `float`?  The *canonical* use of `None` as a default argument is when you need a *mutable* default argument, but that isn't the case here.

There is an argument to made for the reverse -- If you use `None`, then `help` will tell you that the threshold is `None`, which makes some sense from a "read the code as text" perspective.  (after all, you mean that there is no threshold).<sup>1</sup>

Ultimately though, it's mostly just splitting hairs at this point.  Pick a convention, document it and stick with it.  Don't worry about it too much.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>This is made even worse if you have auto-generated documentation (e.g. sphinx) and `sys.float_info.max` doesn't return the same value on computer which generates the documentation compared to the computer which runs the code.  This scenario is a pretty unlikely one -- Most computers these days agree on IEEE, but ...</sup>

Comment: Even if I'm programmer A (which initially wrote the code as you suggests), I don't agree with your (first) motivation. I think that the interface with a default of None is much more clear. The sys.float_info.max value seems to me an implementation detail... Anyway since I've asked for an opinion I will accept the more voted answer...

Answer (score 1):

You can also workaround `None` default values using kwargs

```
def compute_value(**kwargs):
    threshold = kwargs.get('threshold', sys.float_info.max)
    ...
    return value
```

Comment: it seems to me that this approach does not solve the problem. If I pass threshold=None to your function it remains threshold=None after the kwargs.get(...)

Comment: Yes, it doesn't handle `None` value, it just allows distinguish default `None` value with `None` value passed explicitly. As for me, I agree with  @mgilson that passing `None` explicitly is bad idea, it's better to not provide args at all rather than pass `None` as a "biggest float".